# Can I use Microsoft graph to do the following ?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

1. run existing macros with office online excel ?
2. create edit share excel files in and from one-drive through mvc app ?
3. develop an app uses excel totally run online with macros without opening 
   excel locally ?

if possible any good tutorial link would also be very helpful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there probably is no endpoint in Graph API that would allow you to play with Excel macros. Excel Online doesn't support macros as well so even if you have a link, the defined macros won't work.

Source: [Excel Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/excel-concept-overview) [Macros in Excel Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-macros-in-excel-online-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343)

It is however possible to download, share and edit files from OneDrive. Here's the API reference: [OneDrive Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/sharing?view=odsp-graph-online). You can also use the C# SDK for OneDrive: [Github Page](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp)

And here's a link for working with Excel files with C#: [Working with Excel in C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help